# How to find the percentage of coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have an image, and I want to click on some point with coordinates (x, y) in pixels. But What if I have the same image but on the other device with other screen resolution. I want to click the same place, but it will click in another place, since the x, y coordinates are not the same place.

Can I somehow find that place using percents? x% from top and y% from left side.

Comment: We need more details.  How are you loading the image? Any tools you're using? Otherwise the answer is just ((x/max_x_old_image * max_x_new_image), (y/max_y_old_image * max_y_new_image))

Comment: If you know the `x, y` in the original image, and you know the original image size `w1 * h1` as well as the size of the second image `w2 * h2`, the target position in the second image `(w2 * x / w1, h2 * y / w1)` - this is more of a math question than a python question though.

Comment: That's not about 2 images. And not something specific.
I just have 1 random screenshot, and I wanna click the place which is located - for example 10% from top and 13 % from left side. It is gonna be used for a bot, and no matter who is gonna use this bot, maybe tens or even hundred of different resolutions, it is gonna press the same place, since the screenshot is the same.